# How to use 'member function template' in QT5 button classes?

Tags: c++, qt

Now I wrote 2 button classes in QT5, for adding and setting them into the MainWidnow UI, I wrote 2 functions belongs to the maindow file for almost the same operation, each function will receive 2 types of arguments, 1st is the custom button class name, 2nd is the QVector containing several buttons belongs to the same class,  I want to use the member function template, however it doesnt work.

Some codes segments I posted below:

```cpp
// the 2 buttons classes I defined

// pic_btn.h, only show simplified codes
class pic_btn : public QWidget
{
  ...
};

// button.h, only show simplified codes
class button : public QWidget, private Ui::button
{
  ...
};


// In the mainwindow.h, I defined 
protected:
   template<typename v,typename c> void MainWindow ::add_allbtns(v vec ,c btn);

private:
    QVector<button*> btns;
    QVector<pic_btn*> pbtns;

// in the mainwindow.cpp
// the variables btn_names, btn_num,btns_w,btns_h,x_p,offsetY are pre-defined already.

template<typename v,class c> void MainWindow::add_allbtns(v vec ,c btn)
{
    // add buttons,
    for(int i=0;i<btn_num;i++)
    {
      btn *bt=new btn(btn_names[i]);
      vec.push_back(bt);
    }

    //set buttons parent,size and positions
    for(int i=0;i<btn_num;i++)
    {
      vec[i]->setParent(this);
      vec[i]->setGeometry(0,0,btns_w,btns_h);
      vec[i]->move(x_p[i],offsetY);
    }
}


// I want to use it like the way below in the constructor of mainwindow.cpp

   add_allbtns(btns,button);
```

however, this does not work, and the error is :

**bt was not declared in this scope.** which comes from below

```
for(int i=0;i<btn_num;i++)
    {
      btn *bt=new btn(btn_names[i]);
      vec.push_back(bt);
    }
```

btn is a button class name.

Any hints about how to modify it?
Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use templates?

Comment: it is not clear what should be modified and why. Please include a [mcve] and explain what is missing from the code / what is not working as expected.

Comment: If you instance template `MainWindow::add_allbtns()` with `QVector<button*>` (by type deduction), you get a member function which takes the member `btns` by value. This means `btns` is copied and you make changes on this local copy. Hence, the original member `btns` is left unchanged. You should pass the first argument by reference i.e. `void MainWindow::add_allbtns(v &vec, c btn)`.

Answer (score 0):

`btn` is the name of your parameter, not a class name. You should use `c` instead:

```
      c *bt=new c(btn_names[i]);
```

Of course, you will need to fix this in the rest of your function too.

Answer (score 0):

To have all the information available, current compilers tend to require that a template must be fully defined whenever it is used. That includes all of its member functions and all template functions called from those. Consequently, template writers tend to place template definition in header files.

https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/template_declaration_definition_header_implementation_file.php

Try to put your template function implementation in your header file, not in the cpp file.

```
protected:
    template<typename v,class c> 
    void add_allbtns(v vec ,c btn)
    {
        // add buttons,
        for(int i=0;i<btn_num;i++)
        {
            btn *bt=new btn(btn_names[i]);
            vec.push_back(bt);
        }

        //set buttons parent,size and positions
        for(int i=0;i<btn_num;i++)
        {
            vec[i]->setParent(this);
            vec[i]->setGeometry(0,0,btns_w,btns_h);
            vec[i]->move(x_p[i],offsetY);
        }
    }
private:
    QVector<button*> btns;
    QVector<pic_btn*> pbtns;
```